# Klipper: power on before homing

Tags: g-code, homing, power-supply, klipper

I'd like to force Klipper to perform power on (using `M80`) before homing. For this purpose I'm trying to override `G28`:

```
[gcode_macro G28]
rename_existing: G28_BASE
gcode:
  M80
  G28_BASE { rawparams }
```

But for some reason this does not work, I'm getting the following error:

```
G-Code macro rename of different types ('G28' vs 'G28_BASE')
```

Isn't `G28` overridable? Is there any other way to achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the way parameters work differently (`Sx` vs `NAME=x`) for gcode style commands vs Klipper extended ones, the rename has to be to the "same type" of command. `G28_BASE` does not fit the pattern to be considered a "gcode style" one. Use `G9028` or `G28.1` or something instead and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Besides using a different macro, it is also possible to use [[homing_override]](https://www.klipper3d.org/Config_Reference.html#homing_override) which allows you to redefine the homing sequence.

You can write a simple homing_override like (untested!)

```
[homing_override]
axes: xyz
gcode:
  M80
  G28
```

and you are done.

Be aware that this very simple override will home all axes every time homing is called: "G28 X0" will home also Y and Z. You can put checks to home only what is requested, see [here](https://github.com/zellneralex/klipper_config/blob/master/homing.cfg) but it become more involved.

Comment: Thanks, I saw this. But I decided not to use this exactly because of the reason you mentioned: I'd like to be able to pass arguments as is to the default G28 implementation

Comment: If you check the link I provided, he homes only what's being requested by checking "{% if params.X is defined %}{% set home_x = True %}{% endif %}" and so on